# Excel: If Query

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell, target

I am looking for a formula that autopopulates different cells.

So if cell A1 equals A, cell B1 should equal 1, cell C1 equal 1 and cell D1 equal 0.

Is this something that is possible ?

Comment: FYI - With a *single* formula, you cannot populate multiple cells.  For something like that, you need VBA.

Comment: Thanks! Im not to skilled at excel so i guess im out of optoins then as id have no clue how to write that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @pnuts Thanks. What do you want B1, C1, and D1 to be if A1 does not equal "A"?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if statement.

- in B1: `=If(A1="A",1,"")`
- in C1: `=If(A1="A",1,"")`
- in D1: `=If(A1="A",0,"")`

Comment: Thanks, but i would need it to happen with one formula.... if possible.

what i'm trying to do is:

Comment: Each cell must have it's own formula.

Comment: Thanks ,but i would need it with one formula in one cell instead of putting a different formula in the 3 cells ... so it should be something like  =if A1=A then B1 = 1 and C1 = 1 and D1=1

Comment: As Bruce Wayne said, that cannot be done with a single formula. Which begs the question: why would such a thing be needed?